# Codeigniter sessions creating new blank rows

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm using Codeigniter to create a student testing system but for some reason my sessions data seems to be acting strangely. On my login page the user selects their username from a pulldown list (I doesn't have to be secure at this stage) this passes the userid of the selected user to a function which sets up the userdata in the session and then redirects them to the dashboard page. Now my problem is this. when the dashboard page is loaded either by using redirect in the url helper or manually by navigating to localhost/progsqs/dashboard, the session class creates a new, blank, session.

I wrote a few small test functions which do the same thing but they work fine one session with retrievable data (which rules out a codeigniter configuration problem) but for reasons unknown dashboard ALWAYS builds a new blank session and tries to work with it. I'm at my wits end and need a fresh pair of eyes to look at it and see the mistake I've obviously made but cannot for the life of me spot.

```
<?php
class Progsqs extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->login();
    }

    function login()
    {   
        $this->load->model('Progsq_Model');
        $data['users'] = $this->Progsq_Model->getUsers();
        $this->load->view('templates/header.php');
        $this->load->view('progsqs/login.php', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer.php');
    }

    function logout()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect(base_url('progsqs/login'));
    }

    function setUser()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('Progsq_Model');
        $username = $this->Progsq_Model->getUsername($_POST['userlist']);
        $this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);
        echo $this->session->userdata('username');
        //redirect(base_url('progsqs/dashboard'));
    }

    function dashboard()
    {
        echo($this->session->userdata('username'));
        print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
    }
    function profile()
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('progsqs/profile');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

    function testBuilder()
    {

    }
    /*
        Debugging code for repairing session data
    */

    function inputtest()
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('somedata', 'This is a test');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        redirect(base_url('progsqs/testoutput'));
    }

    function outputtest2()
    {
        echo($this->session->userdata('somedata'));
        //print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
    }

    function testoutput()
    {
        $this->load->model('Progsq_Model', '', TRUE);
        $data['users'] = $this->Progsq_Model->getUsers();
        $this->load->view('templates/header.php');
        $this->load->view('progsqs/outputtest.php', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer.php');
    }

    function killsession()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check yout session config file.

an example :

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

If you're matching IP's have 0 in your sess_expiration

also make sure these aren't set :

```
 $config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
 $config['cookie_domain']    = "";
```

i had problems with them before with sessions.

These should be in your config file in your application folder "/application/config/config.php"

edit :

```
        function setUser()
{
    $this->session->set_userdata('username', 'alphabeta');
    header ('Location:' . base_url() . '/go/dashboard');
}

function dashboard()
{
    echo($this->session->userdata('username'));
    print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
}
```

I boiled down your two functions to this. I ran them on my server and it works perfectly.

if function setUser works fine, and you can actually echo out the stuff, and dashboard doesn't work(and creates a new session), I'm all out of ideas, sorry buddy

Comment: my config already looks like that I'm afraid it was the first thing I tried :(
The debug code at the bottom which does exactly what the program is supposed to do works, which suggests my config is fine,  I just can't seem to replicate it where it matters

Comment: just seen your extra code, My bad I missed it ;

Just to be clear, the setUser function works correctly and when you echo $this->session->userdata('username'); you get a result which is fine, right?

Comment: in the second code yes. however the first one generates a whole new session row in the database whenever I navigate to dashboard. This new row's user data is empty. also it seems to occur when dashboard loads with no regard for how it is requested. 
To clarify I stripped out all of the code from the dashboard method so it does absolutely nothing whatsoever, despite this it STILL creates a new empty row on load.

Comment: my bad I didn't read that properly. yes the setUser function works as intended it sets up all the user data within the session but when I move on to dashboard dashboard seems to build a whole new session and tries to use it. however problematically this session is empty so all the calls to $this->session->user data($someelement) return nothing

Comment: Using the edit to your answer it now generates TWO blank rows in the sessions table lol. I got nothin' :(

Comment: Sorry buddy all out of ideas, Something is strange but I can't figure out what